# What's the behavior of $attribute->getFrontendInput() method?

Tags: magento2

Can someone explain me what's the behavior and the return value of `$attribute->getFrontentdInput()`?

I'm using Magento 2.2.7.

Answer (score 2):

The `$attribute->getFrontentdInput()` method returns the way your attribute is rendered, some values are:

```
text -> is rendered as input
select -> is rendered as select-one
boolean -> is rendered as a switch (On/Off)
```

There are also other values.

You can check them by looking at the `eav_attribute` table which stores all the attributes that are in your Magento installation (see the `frontend_input` column).

This is a screenshot from my Magento installation:

[image: eav attribute table]